# What is the best practice to store a class path in database?

Tags: symfony

I would like to know in Symfony2 what is the best way to store a path to a class on a doctrine entity?

I would either like to store the full path to the class or maybe the service id against the entity. I like the way the routing object converts to a controller, is there a method to do this for any class?

Say for example I have a class which needs to be validated by another class. I could store the class path again the object. This way I could do a `$object->getValidator()` and it could automatically create the validation object based on what is stored against it.

The 3 ways I can think of to store this information:

1. full path: `/Acme/BlogBundle/Validator/ValidateClass`
2. service: `acme_validator_class`
3. like routing: `AcmeBlogBundle:Validator:ValidateClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have chosen

```
/Acme/BlogBundle/Validator/ValidateClass
```

way for such situation.

Comment: I like this idea but my only problem is that it makes it impossible to extend that class. With a service you could simply override the definition.

Though in my situation I don't really need to extend the validators so unless someone else comes up with a solution I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Why it makes it impossible? Update or Add a new row in the DB in case you extend.

Comment: Well its possible to update all the rows of the DB but that is not as easy as just overriding some config file setting.